# Stretch duty cycle of square wave where amplitude changes

Tags: pwm, square, duty-cycle

I have a signal coming from a photodiode detector, the pulse is really short, so the integration time is very small, and the total power measured is very small (very close to the noise of the detector). I want to take the signal detected by photodiode (a short square pulse with variable amplitude) and stretch the duty cycle from about 1% to 50% at the same amplitude of the pulse being stretched (which changes from pulse to pulse).

Normally i would use a monostable 555 timer, but i'm not sure how to get the amplitude issue worked out.

Comment: Can you show us an example of the waveform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach - use the trigger pulse to trigger both a monostable and a sample-and-hold (S/H) circuit.  The photodiode pulse triggers the S/H to sample its own trigger signal amplitude.  This creates a buffered output voltage scaled to equal trigger pulse amplitude.  When the monostable circuit times out, use that trailing edge to reset the S/H, driving its output voltage to near 0 V.

Analog Devices (ADI), Linear Technology (LTI, now a part of ADI), and National Semiconductor (now a part of TI) have many S/H parts.

Comment: Be aware that choosing a trigger level is difficult: Pulse amplitude is not detectable below this trigger level, so you'd prefer a low trigger level. Some noise may reach the trigger level and be falsely detected, especially if the trigger level is set too low.